# Use of Acapela tags with Nao robot

Tags: nao-robot

I am writing a program in python, where I want to use Acapela tags (as it is supported by naoqi). Please give a simple example, how to use Acapela tags in speech with Nao robot.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [docs](http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/_downloads/audio_system_acapelamobilitytexttags.pdf) you will see that using the tags is really simple.

For example, if you want to make the robot say the sentence *"Hello World. I am alive"* with a pause between both statements, you have to introduce the tag `\pau=300\` after the dot:

```
sentence = 'Hello World.\\pau=300\\ I am alive'
```

The double `\\` is used in Python to scape the `\` character.

Comment: And don't forget the space after the tag(after the closing '\'). It's mandatory.